# Showing $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{[\ln(x+1)]^{4}}{x^{2}}dx=\frac{4\pi^{4}}{15}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

How to solve this weird integral?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{[\ln(x+1)]^{4}}{x^{2}}dx$$

I know the answer is $\dfrac{4\pi^{4}}{15}$, but I don't know how to get it. I tried to use Gamma-function with no success.

Comment: What is weird about that integral?

Comment: @Gerry Maybe the OP doesn't seem to admire the beauty of integrals. Can't believe this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Performing the substitution $t=\frac{1}{1+x}$ yields
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln ^4\left(1+x\right)}{x^2}\:\mathrm{d}x=\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^4\left(t\right)}{\left(1-t\right)^2}\:\mathrm{d}t$$
Now expand the denominator
$$=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }n\int _0^1t^{n-1}\ln ^4\left(t\right)\:\mathrm{d}t=24\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^4}$$
$$\therefore \int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln ^4\left(1+x\right)}{x^2}\:\mathrm{d}x=\frac{4\pi ^4}{15}$$

Comment: How do you get $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }n\int _0^1t^{n-1}\ln ^4\left(t\right)\:\mathrm{d}t=24\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^4}$? using partial integral formula repeatedly or is a simpler way?

Comment: @Dabed You can it get pretty easily by taking the derivative of $\int_0^1 t^{n-1} dt$ four times with respect to $n$.

Comment: @TomHimler ah yes this is also similar to when we take the derivative of the Riemann zeta but I totally didn't see it, thank you very much